# How to fix URL Encoding?

Tags: php, html, vbulletin

my url is:

```
forumdisplay.php?462-%EE%F9%E7%F7%E9%ED-%E1%F8%F9%FA
```

i think that the url is URL Encoding

im using vbulletin 4.1.12

how i can fix it?

replace 462-%EE%F9%E7%F7%E9%ED-%E1%F8%F9%FA with `f=462`

Comment: What is the problem here, where does the URL come from and where is it being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Until someone comes up with a one-line-preg_replace-solution, this might help:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url(urldecode('forumdisplay.php?462-%EE%F9%E7%F7%E9%ED-%E1%F8%F9%FA'));
$new_query = '?f='.substr($parsed_url['query'], 0, strpos($parsed_url['query'], '-'));
$new_url = $parsed_url['path'].$new_query;
var_dump( $new_url );
```